# Attribute error when I use the readable function in Python

Tags: python-2.7, attributeerror

Here is the code :

```py
K = open("text.txt", "r")
print(K.readable())
```

The name of the text file is text.txt and the name of the python script is ex.py. The python script and the text file are in the same directory. Now when I go to powershell to run python script, I get the following piece of code :

```
 File "ex.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(K.readable())
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readable'
```

What is the reason for the error?

I am still a beginner and I hope the answer to my question to be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the answer to my question by coincidence. The reason I am getting the error is because the function "readable()" is not supported by python 2.7. I know this was the case because when I tried to run the code on an environment using python 3, the error disappeared.

Powershell uses python 2.7, and it always printed the error when I tried to run the code. But when I ran the code on visual studio, I found no error and the reason was that visual studio was using python 3.

In a nutshell, the "readable()" function is not supported by python 2 whereas it is supported by python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
python3 ex.py
```

instead of

```
python ex.py
```